# android "achartengine" show only limited dates in time chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using "achartengine" for time chart,but i want that only that dates or time of day that has data should be shown in chart on x-axis.How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling:

```
renderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);
```

This way you disable the default labels and have labels being displayed for your data.

This method is available starting with the 1.1.0 versions. You can download the 1.1.0-rc2 version [here](http://www.achartengine.org/download/).

Comment: there is no option coming in eclipse as renderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);

Comment: Don't search for options in Eclipse, renderer is of type XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.